# Unable to connect mongoose,mongodb with node js through the nodemon index.js command

Tags: mongoose

I am unable to connect mongoose mongodb with node.js application through vs code... although I have reset my system and keep all the options as default and re download all the tools like node.js, mongodb version 7.0 install mongoose, express all other things necessary to connect with node.js...still I am unable to connect it can anyone help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dQaq.jpg) here is the error image